# Создал скрипт на python для превращения числа в список

Tags: python, скрипт

Вряд ли этот скрипт будет нужен опытным программистам,но это создано для удобства,шо бы не писать много кода:) (скрипт на python для превращения числа в список)  Тоесть ты вводишь 5676 и это превращается в список [5,6,7,6]
https://github.com/MihaTarasov/-/blob/master/modul.py (на гит хаб с файлом)

Comment: `print(list(map(int, str(5676))))` или `print(list(map(int, "5676")))`

Comment: Мало того, что этот скрипт ужасен, так он ещё и не делает того, что заявлено.

Comment: Я все проверял и он выполняет свои задачи...

Comment: А вопрос в чём?

Comment: У меня есть переменная n = 456. Этот скрипт не сможет превратить её в список.

Comment: Так это не так работает,я все в файле закомментил!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эту задачу можно решить в одну строчку, как дал ответ S. Nick

```
# решение в одну строку с отловом ошибок
try:
    lst = list(map(int, list(str(int(input('Введите целое число: '))))))
except ValueError:
    print('Нужно ввести целое число')
```

Решение простым алгоритмом

```
try:
    number_str = input('Введите целое число: ')
    number = int(number_str)

    digit_str_list = list(number_str)
    digit_list = []

    for digit_str in digit_str_list:
        digit = int(digit_str)
        digit_list.append(digit)

    print(digit_list)
except ValueError:
    print('Нужно ввести целое число')
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас велосипед какой-то получился

```py
int_value = 5676
list_int_str = [*str(int_value)]
list_int_int = [*map(int, [*str(int_value)])]

print(list_int_str, list_int_int)
# ['5', '6', '7', '6'] [5, 6, 7, 6]
```